# The PipeLine Contains No Upstream Handle hence discarding packet

Tags: netty

I am using Netty to receive packets but sometimes I get this exception:

> netty the pipeline contains no upstream handlers discarding.
>
> Jun 6, 2011 7:22:13 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
>   WARNING: The pipeline contains no upstream handlers; discarding: [id: 0x443ecfff, /127.0.0.1:62171 => /127.0.0.1:43594] CLOSED
>
> Jun 6, 2011 7:22:13 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
>   WARNING: The pipeline contains no upstream handlers; discarding: [id: 0x443ecfff, /127.0.0.1:62171 => /127.0.0.1:43594] UNBOUND: /127.0.0.1:43594
>
> Jun 6, 2011 7:22:13 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
>   WARNING: The pipeline contains no upstream handlers; discarding: [id: 0x443ecfff, /127.0.0.1:62171 => /127.0.0.1:43594] DISCONNECTED: /127.0.0.1:62171

**Please suggest me what should i do to avoid this exception. Also, I'm getting *Unbound Exception*. What does Unbound really means?**

even i have same problem.

> 223.227.12.144:1024-- device ip and port 
>   this is communicating to my ip 192.168.1.42:1023
>
> Exception:
>   Jan 29, 2014 5:21:16 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
>   WARNING: The pipeline contains no upstream handlers; discarding: [id: 0xc3705d5d, /223.227.12.144:1024 :> /192.168.1.42:1023] UNBOUND
>   Jan 29, 2014 5:21:16 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
>   WARNING: The pipeline contains no upstream handlers; discarding: [id: 0xc3705d5d, /223.227.12.144:1024 :> /192.168.1.42:1023] CLOSED

Comment: I don't see any correlation to hornetq on your question hence I will retag it... if you have hornetq you must provide something about hornetq so we can correlate the errors as we never seen this on hornetq

Comment: Please retag this as hornetq if you provide any more substantion info

Answer (score 0):

This basically means you have no ChannelUpstreamHandler in your ChannelPipeline and so the message was not handled.

Answer (score 0):

The Warning straightly says that, your not using any up-stream or down-stream handlers. if not  your trying to remove the pipeline which is already removed. so please check pipeline exists before removing it or ignore this.

best solution is to ignore this warning because it does not give any problem